# Overload resolution with generics and implicit conversion

Tags: c#, generics, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

This code is not compiled:

```
static class Foo
{
    public static Bar Do(Func<Bar> f) => null;
    public static Bar<TOut> Do<TOut>(Func<Bar<TOut>> f) => null;
}

public class Bar
{
}

public class Bar<TOut>
{
    public static implicit operator Bar<TOut>(TOut i) => null;
}

// Here compiler complains:
// CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'Bar'
// CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type 
// because some of the return types in the block
// are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
Foo.Do(() => 1);
```

My expectation would be that compiler sees the return type of the lambda and that no valid overload can be selected unless `int` is converted to `Bar<int>`.
However, I see that compiler resolves to the first method.

Which part of spec defines this behavior?

Comment: Foo.Do<int>(() => 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specified in [Method Invocations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#method-invocations), when the spec is talking about what method declarations count as a *candidate* for overload resolution, for an invocation of the form `M(A)`:

> The set of candidate methods for the method invocation is constructed. For each method `F` associated with the method group `M`:
>
> - If `F` is non-generic, `F` is a candidate when:
>
>   - `M` has no type argument list, and
>   - `F` is applicable with respect to `A`.
> - If `F` is generic and `M` has no type argument list, `F` is a candidate when:
>
>   - Type inference succeeds, inferring a list of type arguments for the call, and
>   - [...]

Just from those rules, we can see that the non-generic `Do` *is* a candidate, and the generic `Do` is not, because type inference fails. Try commenting out the non-generic `Do`, and you will see that it says something like "type arguments cannot be inferred".

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the full answer, but I have some observations:

**Observation 1**: With removing the non-generic version of `Do`:

```cs
static class Foo
{
    public static Bar Do(Func<Bar> f) => null;
}

public class Bar
{
    public static implicit operator Bar(int i) => null;
}

// CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Foo.Do<TOut>(Func<Bar<TOut>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
Foo.Do(() => 1);
```

, still the compiler can't resolve `Func<Bar<TOut>> f`. So it does not seem that the issue is about picking the wrong overload, but rather compiler not being able to match `() => 1` to `Func<Bar<TOut>> f` implicitly at all.

**Observation 2**: The code below works

```cs
static class Foo
{
    public static Bar Do(Func<Bar> f) => null;
}

public class Bar
{
    public static implicit operator Bar(int i) => null;
}

Foo.Do(() => 1);
```

which shows the compiler is checking implicit conversions.

**Observation 3**: Making the implicit cast operator to take `int` as in input, eventhough makes the operator not practically usable as `TOut` will not be resolved, makes the compiler find the operator:

```cs
static class Foo
{
    public static Bar<TOut> Do<TOut>(Func<Bar<TOut>> f) => null;
}

public class Bar<TOut>
{
    public static implicit operator Bar<TOut>(int i) => null; // Input is `int` now
}
// CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Foo.Do<TOut>(Func<Bar<TOut>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
Foo.Do(() => 1);
```

So all of this combined makes me think that the compiler is just not trying to which generic types would cause the implicit conversion to work.